# Why doesn't the Torah use more efficient ways to say "both" or "each" when describing the Mishkan utensils?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, language, parashat-teruma

In Parshas Terumah, in the description of many of the utensils of the Temple, the Torah seems to be very repetitive in its description of parts that are meant to be the same.  For example, [chapter 25](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0225.htm) verses 33 and 35, among other places.

33:

> three cups made like almond-blossoms in one branch, a knop and a flower; and three cups made like almond-blossoms in the one branch, a knop and a flower

35:

> And a knop under two branches of one piece with it, and a knop under two branches of one piece with it, and a knop under two branches of one piece with it

The Torah has a more efficient way to say both or each- שניהם as in [Numbers 7:13](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/k/k0407.htm) (applying the same operation to two things) or אחת לכל as in [Exodus 26:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9887#showrashi=true&v=2) (applying the same measurement to several things).  Why does the Torah not do so here?

Comment: Note that for 33 there's a difference between Terumah and Vayakhel: in Terumah they're both בַּקָּנֶה הָאֶחֶד, while in Vayakhel the second one is בְּקָנֶה אֶחָד.  However you answer the question of what the Torah is illustrating by this difference (I have a suggestion [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/90258/11532)), it had to use the double expression in order to convey the difference.

Answer (score 1):

[Abarbanel to Shemos 25:30](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Search?mode=basic&t=%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%92%D7%99%D7%93%20%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%A8%D7%94) addresses this question, saying that these repetitions indicate specific structural points about the Menorah.  To be perfectly honest, I don't fully understand it, but here's the quote:

> ואמר וששה קנים יוצאים מצדיה להגיד שיהיה קנה המנורה באמצע ושלש׳ קנים מצד זה וג׳ קנים מצד זה וכולן יהיו יוצאים מצדיה כי כלה מקשה היא **ואמר שלשה גביעי׳ משוקדים וג׳ גביעים וגו׳ להגיד שבקנה האמצעי שהוא גוף המנור׳ יהיו ארבע׳ גביעים לא שלש׳ כאשר הם בשאר הקנים** כי בקנה ההוא היה גביע אחד בירך והשלש׳ למעלה סמוכים לכפתור ופרח ולנר כמו בשאר הקנים עוד צוה שיהיו בקנה האמצעי ההוא שלש׳ כפתורים ומכל אחד מהם יצאו שני קנים אחד לכאן ואחד לכאן כאלו מאותו הכפתור היו יוצאים הקנים ההם וזה שאמר וכפתור תחת שני הקנים. **וכפל לומר זה ג׳ פעמים להגיד שהם ג׳ כפתורים שיוצאים מהם ששת הקנים כמו שזכרתי**.

(If someone can explain/elaborate, please edit this.)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

> ואמר וששה קנים יוצאים מצדיה להגיד שיהיה קנה המנורה באמצע ושלש׳ קנים
> מצד זה וג׳ קנים מצד זה

And it says "And six branches coming out of its sides" to say that there should be a central column with 3 branches coming out on each side.

> וכולן יהיו יוצאים מצדיה כי כלה מקשה היא

And all of them should come out of its sides for it is all one beaten piece.

> ואמר שלשה גביעי׳ משוקדים וג׳ גביעים וגו׳ להגיד שבקנה האמצעי שהוא גוף
> המנור׳ יהיו ארבע׳ גביעים לא שלש׳ כאשר הם בשאר הקנים כי בקנה ההוא היה
> גביע אחד בירך

And it says 3 filigreed goblets and three goblets.. to say that in the central column which is the central body of the *menorah* there should be 4 goblets, not 3, as there are on the other branches because on that central column there was one goblet at its base.

> והשלש׳ למעלה סמוכים לכפתור ופרח ולנר כמו בשאר הקנים

And the three above should be next to the knob and the flower and the lamp, as on the other branches.

> עוד צוה שיהיו בקנה האמצעי ההוא שלש׳ כפתורים ומכל אחד מהם יצאו שני
> קנים אחד לכאן ואחד לכאן כאלו מאותו הכפתור היו יוצאים הקנים ההם וזה
> שאמר וכפתור תחת שני הקנים. וכפל לומר זה ג׳ פעמים להגיד שהם ג׳ כפתורים
> שיוצאים מהם ששת הקנים כמו שזכרתי.

Further it commanded that there should be on that central column three knobs and from each one of them should come out two branches, one on each side, as if the branches came out of that knob, and this is what it means when it says "and a knob under the two branches". And it repeats this three times to tell you that there are 3 knobs from which come out 6 branches, as I have mentioned.

?